# Trying to search a field with or without dashes in a query?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, ms-access

I have a table (table.foo) where I am trying to search for a specific field.  I have an MS Access form that uses a SQL query to output the results.  I have a user who wants to be able to search this field

If I use a simple select query

```
SELECT foo FROM table
WHERE foo LIKE '%xyz%'
```

I will get any string with xyz, but if the user searches for x-yz they obviously won't get any records `where table.foo='xyz'`  How would I go about structuring a query to return results regardless of the presence of dashes in the search string?

I know that I could duplicate the table.foo column and create a table.foo-search column and strip the dashes from the new field, but that seems like that would waste space possibly unnecessarily plus it would require maintaining a second column in the database.

Answer (score 2):

Here you go:

```
select foo from table
where REPLACE ( REPLACE ( foo, '-', '' ) , ' ', '' ) like '%xyz%'
```

OUTPUT: `x-yz`

### [Live Demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/f679e0/1)

Comment: This query does not work in Access as written. It runs, but it returns no rows. It *will* work in Access if you change the wildcard character in the LIKE clause from `%` to `*`.

Comment: @GordThompson May or may not work, depending on ANSI mode, amongst other things yesno? It appears to suit the OP, who is using SQL Server and may, therefore, be using ANSI 92 mode. Changing from LIKE to ALIKE would make it work in both environments.

Answer (score 0):

the following works for me.

```
SELECT Replace([fieldname],"-","") AS Expr1
FROM tablename
WHERE (((Replace([fieldname],"-","")) Like "%xyz%"));
```